# Ensure good security / code signing for builds with Maven + Java + Clojure

Tags: java, security, maven, clojure, code-signing

I have a number of open source projects in Java and Clojure that I build using Maven and deploy to a public repository (clojars.org). I'm using Eclipse as an IDE, git / GitHub for source control, Windows 7 as OS, and PuTTY / pageant for my keys.

This works well, but I'd like to ensure that I follow best practices and sign all of my artifacts so that others can trust them, and also so that I can verify that the artifacts have not been tampered with.

What are the key steps I should take to ensure all my artifacts are correctly signed and verified? Ideally I'd like this to be well integrated into the Maven build process so that I don't have to follow additional manual steps.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? This is almost verging on the "not constructive" discussion-type question. Is it just the mechanisms of signing that interests you?

Comment: I'm asking for the steps required - not discussion (although obviously comments on the rationale behind the steps would be helpful!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Maven GPG plugin docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/) are good starting points for artifact signing.

Comment: is the GPG plugin the standard / recommended approach? are there other options worth considering?

Comment: @mikera, If you plan on deploying to a public Maven repo (I think you mentioned clojars), then it's a fine choice.  Maven is not the only way to package and deploy Java code though.  Regardless, the high-level process is similar though as far as key-pair-generation, signing, public key distribution, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to signing, you need to provide the signatures and public keys somewhere in a place that is not co-located with the Maven repo, e.g. your web site. Otherwise signing does not achieve the goal of raising trust of others, only your own. If I cannot be sure that the signature on the artifact is yours, my trust is not improved.

Answer (score 1):

Just to mention (I know you mentioned maven, but leiningen is a good alternative for Clojure, with built-in Clojars support):

The latest Leiningen preview supports automatic signing with GPG keys as well as automatic clojars deployment with the signed pom/jar. There was a thread on the forums last week (and some complaints that it was slightly broken)--I think it will soon be ready for prime time, and if you're using leiningen, it's probably a great best practice for the Clojure projects.

There are a couple of step by step guides within the discussion. For windows you might want to check out http://www.gpg4win.org/ for gpg support, to generate a key.

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/clojure/AsPs9ZonRPQ/discussion

Once you've configured your GPG public key in clojars, 
`lein deploy clojars` is all you need to do to deploy.